# Similar SVN Server software for OS X that's like Visual SVN

Tags: svn, macos, version-control, visualsvn

My design-house client needs version control to keep all their new source code I'm writing for them. Subversion seems like a good pick,

All their servers are OSX.

Does anyone know of a good OSX server manager for SVN similar to visual SVN for Windows?

The reason i'm looking for one is because I get the feeling their IT guy is apprehensive to install anything or add anything to the infrastructure. I want to smooth the process as much as possible for him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have said, Versions is a really nice subversion client for OS X. What it is not however, is a svn *manager* like VisualSVN. I've been looking for a while but haven't been able to find anything similar for OS X. Visual SVN, as you may or may not know, is really just a management console around a specialized apache installation. It works really well, but aside from being convenient there's little difference between VisualSVN and simply rolling your own apache set up.

You might want to check out (no pun intended) SVN Manager:
http://svnmanager.sourceforge.net/

Supposedly it should do what you want and in fact by the description it sounds as if it's technically the same as VisualSVN (Apache set up). I haven't tried it (yet) though so I couldn't tell you if or how well it works.

Let me know if you find anything useful!

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Versions](http://versionsapp.com/) for OSX

Comment: Versions is, by far, the best OSX subversion client I've used.  It's too bad it costs $$$

Comment: Thanks, Versions is a great client! does it have any server functionality though?

Comment: CVertex - pretty much everyone gets the Subversion open source server (or uses an online service like http://www.beanstalkapp.com) and then buys/uses a Client.  So, yes, Versions is a client but this is where all the competition is.  I use Beanstalk on a paid plan.  They do offer a free plan as well

Comment: Thanks Mark. I've laid out beanstalk as one option for my client. It's up to them though. Personally. I would just run svnserve cos I'm not afraid of the command line

Comment: I particularly like Beanstalk because A) I don't have to run another Internet-facing server app and B) I code from two different locations so I need the svn server to be on the net.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at [Cornerstone](http://www.zennaware.com/cornerstone/). [This article](http://jadeohlhauser.com/2008/c_vs_v/) compares Cornerstone with Versions and loops through other Mac SVN clients as well, though it doesn't seem to cover [SynchroSVN](http://www.syncrosvnclient.com/)

There's also SVN's [own list of clients](http://subversion.tigris.org/links.html#clients)..

Answer (score 1):

[BinaryMethod](http://www.binarymethod.com) is working on a server manager for Mac OS X. They haven't released it yet, but you could ask to beta test it. The tool is called [SvnXact](http://www.binarymethod.com/content/svnxact.php).